# Change the font size in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, visual-studio-2019, codelens

What is this font in the Visual Studio options?

[image]

I changed the general font to Consolas 6, and I had all other fonts updated automatically, but this one of the comments that remain still too huge. How can I update it manually?

Bellow is the my Visual Studio 2019 options window
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the size of the `CodeLens` font:

1. Open Options (Tools -> Options)
2. Go to Environment -> Fonts and Colors
3. Choose `CodeLens` from the `Show settings for` dropdown.
4. Change the font as needed.

See the attached screenshot:

[image: CodeLens Font Settings]

Comment: Thanks for answering. Please see my update in the OP, I have no "CodeLens" in my Visual Studio 2019...

Comment: You are clicking the wrong drop down.  See again step 3 - use the `Show settings for` drop down (you are using `Display items`).